# Maintainable Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 excel spreadsheet. page 1 is a questionnaire and page 2 is a requirements page. so to break it down even further, users will answer the questionnaire by ticking on checkboxes next to the column of the question. each question will result in a different requirement being shown on the requirements page. my question is, what would be a better way to reference the required rows to be shown other than just referencing their row number.

[image]

[image]

so lets say, ive decided to add a new question and name it Question 5 - Show Requirement 5, everything after the index 5 will have to increase by 1, in turn, my macros that reference to the row number after index 5 will all have to increase by 1. so what would be a better way in getting this done?

Comment: Please post [a sample of your data rather than images](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) - see [ask] and [mre] for more details

Comment: I would use a table (insert - table) with two columns: requirements, select. Then you code the selection change event of the sheet - any time user clicks in "select"-column value of that cell, code writes an X (if empty) or clears the cell if previously selected. (rest of the sheet is protected - no manual changes by the user). Then you can use the `FILTER`- function on Sheet 2 to show only the selected requirments.

Comment: Can I suggest you look at using Microsoft Forms? The questionnaire results still get passed to an excel spreadsheet, and changes like this to the questions get automatically updated on the backend.

Comment: See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how to format markup tables.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes love the suggestion, however, how would i go about just showing the requirements in the excel spreadsheet?